# Matplotlib equivalent of Matlab's cellplot()

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, visualization

There is a `cellplot()` function in Matlab which visualizes the contents of a cellarray. I would like to visualize the contents of a Python tuple in similar manner. Is there a function in Matplotlib or any other python library to achieve this ? Thanks.

For example, A cell array in Matlab could be

```
A = {['1st element'] [2 3] [8 9 7; 1 2 3] ['a' 'b']};
```

The output of `cellplot(A)` :
[image]

Comment: Can you post some example Matlab code/data, and possibly an example image of what Matlab produces for that data?

Comment: @Marius: Hi, I've edited the question to include Matlab code and the resulting visualization.

Comment: The plot MATLAB produces here is based on MATLAB's data types- orange for character arrays, red for numeric arrays, recursively diving down into the cell if it contains a cell itself. Since this doesn't seem to exist in `matplotlib` at the moment, you would have to think about which Python datatypes you want represented if you were going to write your own. Python datatypes don't match up directly with MATLAB, so a lot of that would be up to you.